# Can not Scrape complete html table

Tags: vba, web-scraping, html-table

I want to get the stock data of the web https://tw.stock.yahoo.com/class-quote?sectorId=4&exchange=TAI.

The vba code is as follows:

```
Dim objXMLDoc As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, objHTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, objTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

objXMLDoc.Open "GET", "https://tw.stock.yahoo.com/class-quote?sectorId=4&exchange=TAI", False

objXMLDoc.send

objHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objXMLDoc.responseText

Set objTable = objHTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("C($c-button) C($c-active-text):h Td(n)")
```

The Problem is:

There are 45 stocks, but objTable (and of course objHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML) contains olny the data of first 30 ones.

Chrome browser shows the complete data of 45 stocks, but in Chrome/Developer Tools/Sources, the html document also contains only the data of the first 30 ones.

How can I scrape the complete data?

Comment: This page implements lazy loading. Meaning, as you scroll the site will execute additional web requests to get the next X rows. If you monitor the web requests using Dev Tools, you'll see the additional requests you could make to get the content needed.

Comment: Dev Tools/Network does show a link that contains the data of stock 31-45.  I can parse the long string obtained.  Thanks Ryan.